# ggplot2: How to remove one level in one facet only?

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet

Here is a reproducible example

```
set.seed(12)
d = data.frame(
  x = rep(LETTERS[c(2,1,3,4)],each=30),
  y=rnorm(120),
  facet = c(rep("facet 1", 20), rep("facet 3", 10), rep(rep(paste("facet",1:3), each=10),3))
 )

require(ggplot2)
ggplot(d,aes(x=x,y=y)) + geom_boxplot() + facet_grid(.~facet)
```

[image]

As you can see, in `facet 2`, there is no entry for `x == "B"`.

**How can I remove the empty space and tick `B` for `facet 2` only?**

The horizontal width of `facet 2` will then be 3/4 of that of the other facets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to set both, `scales = "free_x"` and `space = "free_x"`:

```
require(ggplot2)
ggplot(d,aes(x=x,y=y)) + geom_boxplot() +
    facet_grid(.~facet, scales = "free_x", space = "free_x")
```

[image]

`scales = "free_x"` allows the x-axis to differ among facets. Therefore, in the second facet the missing level will be omitted.

`space = "free_x"` allows for different spatial width of the facets. According to the documentation:

> if "free_x" their width will be proportional to the length of the x scale;

where "their width" refers to the width of the facets.